# Emacs: remembering last position of cursor

Tags: emacs, bookmarks

Is there a way to save a file so that when reopening it, it brings me to the last known position of my cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [SavePlace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SavePlace). It saves the last position of the cursor when a file is closed and re-positions the cursor at the same place when reopening the file.